# Windows 7 64bit booting to black screen with mouse cursor

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I'm using Windows 7 professional 64bit. Windows boots up to the login screen no problem, but once I log in the loading time is very slow. Windows then boots to a black screen with just the mouse cursor showing, this stays like this for about 10 minutes before the desktop and icons slowly start appearing. This started seemingly randomly one day, I updated the display drivers but the issue still occurred. The issue does not occur when booting into safe mode. I tried restoring Windows to an earlier system image I had made - this resolved the issue for about a week or so but it has started again now. I have run multiple antivirus scans and confirmed that Windows and all my drivers are up to date.
I also have a dual boot to Debian Linux installed on this PC - I do not experience any issues at all with Linux.

PC performs fine once the desktop has loaded up without crashes or bugs, it's just this very long booting process. I have Windows installed on a 120GB Kingston SSD.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Edit:
Having followed iTechieGamer's advice I thought I had narrowed the issue down to a bad USB drive. A couple of days later however the issue has come back again, this time without that drive connected. The only windows event errors are 2 entries for event 11 "The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Ide\IdePort 0" and "IdePort1" from source "atapi". I'm not really sure what that means and from my Googling  can only really decipher that it's often pointing to a hardware fault. Any thoughts?

Comment: A program at startup might be the problem.. Try to open `Event Viewer`, then navigate to `Windows Logs` > `System` and check to see for any startup errors/warnings.

Comment: Had a look at the event log, lots of events pointing to a fault with a USB hard drive I had connected. Tried the windows disk check which said it had made repairs but no joy, same issue and events. Unplugged the hard drive and the issue went away immediately. I am now getting an event saying there was a controller error on IdePort1, might this suggest a larger issue that was responsible for killing that last drive?